Installing pycddlib on Windows Failed building wheel
I’m trying to install pycddlib on my Windows system, using the latest version of Python (3.13.0). Unfortunately, I keep running into errors (ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycddlib) during the installation.
I’ve already attempted to build it from source following the instructions here:
https://pycddlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installing-cddlib-and-gmp
but I still encounter the same issue. I’ve also checked similar threads, like "pip building wheel fails for pycddlib," but I haven’t been able to resolve the problem.
If anyone has successfully installed pycddlib on Windows or has any advice, I’d greatly appreciate your guidance. Please let me know if you need additional details about my setup or the error messages I’m receiving.
Thank you in advance!

The current latest version of pycddlib 3.0.0 provides wheels for Python 3.9-3.12 but not 3.13. My advice is to use Python 3.12 to avoid compiling pycddlib.
